# Test whether dataframe only contains same data type

Tags: r

Can't seem to find a simple or elegant (to me) way of testing whether a dataframe contains only numeric, or only factor, etc.

My solution so far is:

```
all(sapply(x, is.numeric)) |
    all(sapply(x, is.factor)) |
    all(sapply(x, is.character))
```

But I am pretty sure there is a better way... **So the question is**... is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
length(unique(sapply(iris, class))) == 1
#[1] FALSE                            # iris contains different column classes
length(unique(sapply(mtcars, class))) == 1
#[1] TRUE                             # mtcars contains only 1 column class
```

Comment: Geez, shoulda thought of that... very nice